# ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool - Error during export: Export job failed

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

we are trying to export the data from HDFS to mysql using sqoop, and facing the following issue.

Sample data:

```
4564,38,153,2013-05-30 10:40:42.767,false,No credentials attempted,,,00 00 00 00 01 64 e6 a6

4565,38,160,2013-05-30 10:40:42.767,false,No credentials attempted,,,00 00 00 00 01 64 e6 a7

4566,38,80,2013-03-07 12:16:26.03,false,No SSH or Telnet credentials available. If an HTTP(S) exists for this asset, it was not able to authenticate.,,,00 00 00 00 01 0f c7 e6
```

Following Sqoop program, we used to export data from HDFS to MYSQL and we specified the schema in table:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] str = { "export", "--connect", "jdbc:mysql://-------/test", 
            "--table", "status", "--username", "root", "--password", "******", 
            "--export-dir", "hdfs://-----/user/hdfs/InventoryCategoryStatus/", 
            "--input-fields-terminated-by", ",", "--input-lines-terminated-by", "\n"
            };

        Sqoop.runTool(str);
    }
```

Error after program execution:

```
[exec:exec]
0    [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.tool.SqoopTool  - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
123  [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
130  [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory  - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
Note: /tmp/sqoop-manish/compile/fd0060344195ec9b06030b84cdf6e243/status.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
9516 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
11166 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
16598 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.speculative
16612 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative
16614 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
16618 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase  - SQOOP_HOME is unset. May not be able to find all job dependencies.
17074 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
17953 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - mapred.job.classpath.files is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.classpath.files
17956 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - mapred.cache.files is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.cache.files
17957 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
17958 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - mapred.mapoutput.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.value.class
17959 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
17959 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
17959 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - mapreduce.inputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.inputformat.class
17960 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
17960 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - mapreduce.outputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.outputformat.class
17960 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - mapred.cache.files.timestamps is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.cache.files.timestamps
17961 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - mapred.mapoutput.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.key.class
17961 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
19283 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager  - LocalJobRunner does not support symlinking into current working dir.
19312 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - mapred.cache.localFiles is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.cache.local.files
20963 [Thread-29] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  - job_local_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " it was not able to authenticate."
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:400)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " it was not able to authenticate."
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)
    at status.__loadFromFields(status.java:412)
    at status.parse(status.java:334)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:77)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:232)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
21692 [main] WARN  mapreduce.Counters  - Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
21698 [main] WARN  mapreduce.Counters  - Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
21699 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool  - Error during export: Export job failed!
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 30.419s
Finished at: Fri Aug 23 15:28:03 IST 2013
Final Memory: 14M/113M
```

---

After, we checked the mysql table contain only 100 records out of 1600 records. Same program, we executed on another tables then out of 8000 records only 6800 records and 235202 records out of 376927 records got exported into mysql table. Can anyone please provide some suggestion regarding above program execution error.

Looking forward to reply, your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your examples it seems that you are using comma as a column (field) separator, however you are allowing the comma to be part of the data itself. Notice the third line from the example data:

```
4566,38,80,2013-03-07 12:16:26.03,false,No SSH or Telnet credentials available. If an HTTP(S) exists for this asset, it was not able to authenticate.,,,00 00 00 00 01 0f c7 e6
```

The 6th column (No SSH ...) contains comma inside. As a result this one column will be split by Sqoop as two different columns and hence the exception you are getting. I would suggest to clean up your data. If you are using Sqoop to import them into HDFS, you can use parameters --enclosed-by or --escaped-by to overcome this issue.

Comment: Thanks Jarek, i used flume to import the data into HDFS and now trying to export them into MySql. Well, i understood your explanation regarding 6th column contains comma inside. Can we use --enclosed-by or --escaped-by during export to overcome this issue. I need "No SSH or Telnet credentials available. If an HTTP(S) exists for this asset, it was not able to authenticate." as a single 6th column.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be having a string where a number expected like  " it was not able to authenticate." (as I can see from the trace that you shared). Please check the source data that is being pushed to the database.

**Edit**

Use some other character as the delimiter. When the data is being written (I assume that a MR program is generating this data.) to HDFS, use a rare character (like ^A, #, @) as a delimiter.

There are various options in the 'export' command such as '--enclosed-by', ' --escaped-by'. But your data should be prepared accordingly. The simplest option looks to be to select a delimiter character that is highly improbable to occur inside your data.

**Edit-2**
In that case, there's nothing much any tool can do as the delimiter character is coming in between the data field without any escape character or without enclosing strings (like "Hello, How are you"). The data needs to be controlled while storing. So while extracting through flume you should use a different delimiter than ',' OR escape ',' (like "Hello\, How are you") characters OR be able to enclose each field ("Hello, How are you").

So you should achieve this while extracting and storing data through flume. You should explore if there are any options on flume for achieving these.

Alternately you can write a MR program to cleanse or filter out problem records (to handle separately) OR load data into a staging table on MYSQL and write an SP to hadle the problem record scenario and insert into target table.

Comment: Thanks Rags, I used flume to import the data into HDFS which is already in CSV and now trying to export them into MySql. I need "No SSH or Telnet credentials available. If an HTTP(S) exists for this asset, it was not able to authenticate." as a single 6th column. MySql Schema is created according to the data but if i will specify the delimiter as "," then its stored in table as 6th column "No SSH or Telnet credentials available. If an HTTP(S) exists for this asset" and 7th column "it was not able to authenticate." Can we sort out that problem using '--enclosed-by', ' --escaped-by'?